# AngularJs filtering with uib-typeahead is not working

Tags: angularjs, filter, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have an app using angular uib-typeahead.

The data are loaded remotely by ajax call.

I need filter the result to show only the results with  "name" containing  $viewValue string.

Here is my code. My problem is that the data is never filtered.

What am I doing wrong?

//markup

```
<input type="text" ng-model="modelo.tuss" placeholder="Select TUSS" 
    uib-typeahead="item as item.name for item 
    in getTabelaTUSS($viewValue) | filter:{name:$viewValue}" 
class="form-control">
```

//controller

```
angular.module("clinang").controller('exameCtrl',['$scope', function($scope) {
      var prof=[{"id":1,"name":"John Prof"},
      {"id":2,"name":"Mary Prof"}];

      $scope.getTabelaTUSS = function(val) {
        return dataService.getTabelaTUSS().then(function(response){
             return prof; //only to simulate results to test
    });
  };

}]);
```

**Updated Controller:**

```
//first option - geting rid off view filter and making local filter in controller
angular.module("clinang").controller('configAgendaAddProcedimentosCtrl',['$scope','dataService','$state','$filter',function($scope,dataService,$state,filter){
      $scope.getTabelaTUSS = function(val) {
        return dataService.getTabelaTUSS().then(function(response){
                 return filterFilter(response.data, val); 
        });
      };
}]);

 //second option - using view filter and no local filter in controller
 //I also tried without success
angular.module("clinang").controller('configAgendaAddProcedimentosCtrl',['$scope','dataService','$state','$filter',function($scope,dataService,$state,filter){
      $scope.getTabelaTUSS = function(val) {
        return dataService.getTabelaTUSS().then(function(response){
                 return response.data; 
        });
      };
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you replace the following block with `return prof;`, it will work as expected as I demonstrate in [this Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/pNvEug61WLgWNarKll4e?p=preview)

```
return dataService.getTabelaTUSS().then(function(response){
  return prof; //only to simulate results to test
});
```

The problem with your `return` statement is it returns a promise object which is returned by `dataService.getTabelaTUSS().then()` call. To fix this, instead of returning `prof` within `then`, assign `prof` to a scope variable and use it in your view.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will explain better. I have used prof only to test, as I said in commented code, I really  need the "response.data" from promise and also, I need filter "response"  using "$viewValue" into view or into controller.

Comment: @LuizAlves I understood and my suggestion can also be applied. Assign `response.data` to a scope variable and use it in your view.

Comment: Hi, It doesnt work. I have tried filter into controller as:       $scope.getTabelaTUSS = function(val) {
        return dataService.getTabelaTUSS().then(function(response){
                 return filterFilter(response.data, val);
        });
      };
or into view using "return response.data;" but nothing works.

Comment: @LuizAlves I believe you still return a promise object instead the data. Update your code in your question, I'll have a look.

Comment: @LuizAlves Check out my update. That's what I mean with assigning data to a scope variable and using it in the view. You're not doing that. You still return a promise object and use the promise object in the view.

Comment: Hi, If I play with your code, I have no way to trigger getTabelaTUSS when I type something to filter into input tag

Comment: @LuizAlves Could you paste a sample of `response.data` here?

Comment: Of course:  [{"id":"20104014","nome":"Actinoterapia"},
{"id":"20104081","nome":"Curativos em geral"},
{"id":"20104090","nome":"Curativo de extremidades"},
{"id":"20104103","nome":"Curativos em geral"}]

Comment: @LuizAlves The attribute name is `nome` not `name`. You use `item.name` and `name` in the filter. Use `nome` instead.

Comment: Yes, I know. I translated to english when I posted it. But it´s not my problem.

Comment: @LuizAlves If an attribute is named `xyz`, to access it you have to use its exact name which is `xyz` not `xyz_in_english`.

Comment: Yes, I understand. My attributes are ok. I mean that when I posted the question I did some translations. The correct is item.nome. The problem is with promises, but I don´t know how to solve it.

Comment: @LuizAlves Did you do a `console.log` within your controller to print out `response.data`? I suspect `response.data` doesn't contain the array of data that you expect.

Comment: Could we move to chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141805/discussion-between-hoa-and-luiz-alves).

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `dataService.getTabelaTUSS()` method but you never injected `dataService` in your controller.

Inject `dataService` in your controller as follows.

```
angular.module("clinang").controller('exameCtrl',['$scope','dataService' function($scope,dataService) {
  var prof=[{"id":1,"name":"John Prof"},
  {"id":2,"name":"Mary Prof"}];

   $scope.getTabelaTUSS = function(val) {
      return dataService.getTabelaTUSS().then(function(response){
          return prof; //only to simulate results to test
    });
  };

}]);
```

Note: Do not forget to include `dataService` service file in your HTML code.

Also if we see the code you are not using the `dataService.getTabelaTUSS()` method `response` instead you are returning the `prof`object. So if you don't need data from service then update your method as follows.

```
$scope.getTabelaTUSS = function(val) {
   return prof;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I use dataService. For simplificity, I ommited it  As I said above, I really  need the "response.data" from promise and also, I need filter "response"  using "$viewValue" into view or into controller.

Comment: If you want filter over "response" then inject the dataService as I mentioned above.